# What is the most reliable countersurveillance method to find hidden cameras?

Tags: camera, internet-of-things

Are there any reliable and inexpensive ones you can reccommend please? Was looking into thermal heat imagers as one way since I dont know if the cameras emit RFs. Apologies if this is not the proper place to ask may you direct me where.